# Sending continuous data to remote machine using Simulink TCP/IP send block

Tags: python, tcp, raspberry-pi3, simulink, remote-server

I am trying to send a continuous-time data from Simulink simulation to a Raspberry Pi within the same network. All I am getting at the receiving end is the random unreadable characters. Is it because of the data type mismatch??

Or do I need to add a decoding block in my code (written in python) to get the correct format??

What would be the correct data type at the input port of TCP/IP Send block?

Comment: where is the difference to your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/59957624/2732801

Comment: Daniel, both the questions are basically the same. All I am getting is the random unreadable characters instead of constant value (which in my case is 1). I could not figure out if the error is on sending end or receiving end. Can you please help me if i have error in my code??